# Trying to transfer xml data into SQL as elements (not attribute)

Tags: sql-server, xml, attributes, element

I am new at this so please bear with me. I am attempting to transfer some XML data into Microsoft SQL Server. I am assuming that this data needs to be transferred as elements and not attributes because the contents of the columns will not be static.

However for some reason when I attempt to transfer the data as elements I get NULL values. But when I try to transfer this same data as attributes it works and looks the way it is supposed to. I am tempted to shrug and just move on but I'm worried that things might go awry for me if I do that later on down the road.

I already have some attributes from this XML that I managed to transfer as attributes which I plan to combine with these elements that are masquerading as attributes into a single table. Will it work? And if it does will there be problems down the road?

Here is my SQL code when I attempt to transfer the elements as elements:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/voter', 2)
WITH (
id int,
[value] char(50),
[state] char(2))
```

Here is my SQL code when I attempt to transfer the elements as attributes:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/voter', 1)
WITH (
id int,
[value] char(50),
[state] char(2))
```

Here is a miniaturized version of the XML document:

```
<roll>
<voter id="400048" value="Yea" state="FL" />
<voter id="412516" value="Yea" state="CA" />
</roll>
```

Here is a link to the xml document via google drive (very small XML): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5VgOwWcGeLHaWctRU56Qlk3UWM

[A screenshot of my SQL query, the table results, and the XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhzZJ.png)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but the proper syntax for the first one is `FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/voter', 2) WITH (id int '@id', [value] char(50) '@value', [state] char(2) '@state')` or something like that.

Comment: @ZLK 
Using the aliases I was able to make the transfer as elements work. Are aliases necessary to make elements work but unnecessary for attributes?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why the aliases were necessary for the first query.

Comment: The flag `2` is for checking the attributes. Basically the format is `columnname columntype attribute`. So e.g. you could have written it  `FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/voter', 2) WITH (AWESOMECOLUMNNAME1 int '@id', AWESOMECOLUMNNAME2  char(50) '@value', AWESOMECOLUMNNAME3 char(2) '@state')`. For the flag `1` they are unnecessary.

Comment: @ZLK so are you saying that the method I choose really doesn't matter because the end result is this same?

Comment: For your particular scenario, there's basically no difference. For a scenario that involves both attributes and element values (e.g. `<voter id="400048" value="Yea" state="FL">something1</voter>`), there's a slight difference, but nothing major. But that's it, really.

Comment: @ZLK for the ones you just mentioned I decided to use aliases and 2. It seemed to work out fine for me. Whatever this slight difference may be I think I have dealt with it. Thank you very much for your help and patience!

Comment: @ZLK `FROM OPENXML` is outdated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used anymore (rare exceptions exist)...

Try with the *real XML methods*:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<roll>
<voter id="400048" value="Yea" state="FL" />
<voter id="412516" value="Yea" state="CA" />
</roll>';

SELECT @xml.value(N'(/roll/voter/@id)[1]',N'int') AS voter_id
      ,@xml.value(N'(/roll/voter/@value)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS voter_value
      ,@xml.value(N'(/roll/voter/@state)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS voter_state
```

The result

```
voter_id    voter_value voter_state
400048      Yea         FL
```